A question about the Notion of Limits in Mathematics
When we say ( Lim{x → x0} f(x) = k ), are we implying exact equality or merely approaching?

Already discussed since Newton and George Berkeley.

Why do you think there are philosophical inconsistencies? What specific inconsistency do you have in mind? The fact that physical systems do not have properties that tend to zero does not mean there is anything wrong with abstract mathematics.

@MauroALLEGRANZA Do you have any books or resources I can read on this discussion?

"When we say 'lim_{x to x0} f(x) = k', are we implying exact equality or merely approaching?" The limit is a number. The *symbol "lim_{x to x0}" is defined in a certain way and - when existing - is a number.

The notion if "limit" is quite reliable: we used calculus to compute the path of the rocket landing on the Moon: it worked.

I believe it depends on what you mean by "abstraction." However, in the mathematical realm, often referred to as abstract, we need to maintain consistency when using this precise language. Therefore, saying "equals" and saying "approaches" are essentially different -if not orthogonal- ways of expressing concepts.

@MauroALLEGRANZA classical physics works -to specific cases- but it doesn't mean it's universally correct.

As the independent variable(s) gets closer to a specified value, the function gets closer to a specific value. That value the function approaches is called the limit. That limit/value is a mathematical truth for any function with a limit. It’s a truth because we can define and calculate it without mathematical inconsistency. We can’t deny a mathematical truth, that’s the greatest sin in math.

As an electrical engineer I learned to think of the applied math as "the geometry and properties of materials." In Physics the math models refer to geometry and properties. This six minute video shows how limits are used to find the exact solution for a problem involving the impulse-momentum integral: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pt-pugEKhLk. The derivative is the slope of a line tangent to a curve at a point which is the well defined limit value in terms of the geometry. In physical systems limit is the rate of change at an instant of time or in terms of some other continuous variable.

@SystemTheory Thank you for your response. I watched the video, and it was interesting. However, the video is based on the assumption that what I've stated above is incorrect (or perhaps doesn't consider whether it's right or wrong), which is perfectly acceptable. Yet, this doesn't address the core question we're discussing in any meaningful way.

This site has no Latex unfortunately. Ive converted your formatting to "poor-man's Latex". Needless to say keep/reject/modify to your taste

@Rushi Alright, thank you.

You should study Real Analysis if you want a formal version of limit. What it means for a function f(x) to "approach" a value L, means that, for any positive value ε, eventually, ( for x "big enough") every value f(X) for X > x is ε away from L i.e | f(X) - L | < ε.

@MichaelCarey Thank you. the question I was having was a bit different than this. it was about how the people are interpreting the limit and how they use the wordings wrongly. However, nothing wrong is with the limit I learned from the books and real analysis classes.

You wrote in a comment below that "we should say "it approaches," and we should replace the '=' sign with '→'."  It is indeed correct that for a sequence (x_n) tending to L one has x_n → L.  Note that this is all that is meant by the formula lim x_n = L.  On the other hand, you may feel that a lot of information is lost when one retains merely the limiting value L and disregards the asymptotic behavior of the sequence.  ...

... This is a valid point and in fact the asymptotic behavior was exploited by Peano in a 1910 article (where he spoke of the "end  behavior" of a sequence), as well as many people after him.

@MikhailKatz Thank you for your response, That's exactly what I wanted to ask about.


When we say ( \lim_{x \to x_0} f(x) = k ), are we implying exact equality or merely approaching?

The terms of the sequence approach... the limit.  Yes, it is an/the exact value.  Formally, the definition of limit is that some sequence or function tends to some limit L iff some conditions are satisfied, where L is, if it is, the value of the limit.
For example, the limit of the series 0, 0.3, 0.33, 0.333, etc. is exactly 0.(3), aka 1/3.  It's the single terms of the series that approach the limit, the limit itself is a number.

The term 'equals' implies certainty, yet the inherent uncertainties in quantum systems reflect the ambiguities we encounter when dealing with infinities or discussing singularities like in black holes.

But "limit" is a notion of mathematics, not one of physics, and, as far as I can tell, there is nothing ambiguous or even particularly problematic about it (unless one is a uber-finitist of some sort, but that's altogether another issue).
In fact, to find a philosophical significance to these notions, we should go back to the Pythagoreans and the scandal that went with the discovery of incommensurable quantities, later the irrational numbers; and, before that, to Zeno's paradoxes where already, again in modern terms, the discovery is that of mathematical answers that cannot be expressed finitely (e.g. the answer in Achilles and the Tortoise is exactly 10.(1) metres, but that is the result of taking a limit...)
But those stories have more of a historical and maybe a foundational interest, the notion of "limit" nowadays is rather unproblematic (modulo, as said, some extreme positions), and occurs all over the place including in category theory: concrete realizations of the notion of limit may differ and even be in conflict with each other, but there we go into the finer technical details of a mathematical treatment, and any issues remain at best issues of philosophy of mathematics.

Thank you for the clear explanation."" The limit of the series 0, 0.3, 0.33, 0.333, etc., is indeed exactly 0.(3), which is equivalent to 1/3."" I understand this part, but I find the assertion a bit weak. Using the word 'exactly' suggests certainty, but the formal definition of a limit doesn't necessarily guarantee absolute certainty about the result.
You might argue that I'm mixing philosophical and physical concepts with abstract ones, but I believe my argument holds true both in abstract mathematics and in real-world applications.

@HAMDIABDERRAHMENE  The/a formal definition of limit has nothing ambiguous or imprecise, my explanation (as others') makes just that clear: and you are not even confused, you are actually denying facts, here without any argument at all, elsewhere with plain inconsistent and/or invalid arguments: e.g. the Banach-Tarski paradox may be genuinely problematic, but it is not a problem with limits.  In my opinion, you do are confusing things.

@HAMDIABDERRAHMENE, you are mistaken. It is certain that the limit of the indicated series is 1/3. If you were to apply this number to some measurement, then the measurement would have precision limits based on the measurement technique, but that doesn't mean that the mathematics itself is in any sense uncertain.


The limit of a sequence of real numbers is a well-defined concept,
and similarly the continuity of a function of real numbers. Since
more than 100 years there are no more inconsistencies in the
mathematical  limit-definition.

The standard definition of continuity of a function f: A - - > R, A
open subset of the set R of real numbers,  is the “epsilon-delta”-
definition:

lim_{x to x_0} f(x) = f(x_0)
if and only if
for each epsilon > 0 exists a delta > 0 such that for all x with |x -
x_0| < delta holds |f(x) - f(x_0)| < epsilon.

Note that all numbers in the    definition are finite values. See
also     https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_function,
Weierstrass and Jordan definitions (epsilon–delta) of continuous
functions.



Thank you for your response.
Regarding the first point, I don't believe this serves as a valid argument because science evolves quickly. Concepts we once thought were well-defined often turn out not to be, requiring us to revise and update them. A brief glance at the history of logic and the debates among figures like Russell, Quine, Frege, and Wittgenstein illustrates that we continually strive to improve our understanding due to inherent inconsistencies in our current knowledge.
As for the second point, it seems to be a circular argument, as that's precisely what I was discussing.

@HAMDIABDERRAHMENE First point: It is not convincing to argue against a precise and successful definition from calculus by  pointing to general discussions in the history of logic. Please indicate explicitly what seems inconsistent in the epsilon-delta definition. (1/2)

@HAMDIABDERRAHMENE Second: The mathematical limit concept formalizes in a precise way the intuitive concept of the limit as an infinite approach nearer and nearer. It is a big achiemement to formalize the concept of infinitely steps of approach by the above definition with finite quantities. One cannot argue against the mathematical concept by pointing to Heisenberg’s uncertainty principle. The analogy to applying classical physics to quantum systems is misleading.  (2/2)

Firstly, It's factual that calculus has a well-defined framework with the epsilon-delta definition but that doesn't mean it's beyond critique or scrutiny. The point isn't to dismiss the definition outright but to question whether it fully captures the richness and complexity of the concept it aims to represent. pointing out to  the success and precision of the epsilon-delta definition doesn't address the philosophical nuances I'm raising.

Secondly, the idea that mathematical concepts can't be challenged or compared to principles from other disciplines is a narrow view -it's a red herring in a sense. The Heisenberg uncertainty principle serves as an illustrative example, not a direct comparison. The point isn't to equate the two but to highlight the limitations and ambiguities that can arise when dealing with concepts like "approaching infinity" or "exactness."

My analogy about applying classical physics to quantum systems isn't misleading; it's a way of illustrating the potential pitfalls of taking a concept and  apply it uncritically.

@HAMDIABDERRAHMENE Yes, but you haven't pointed out any inconsistencies in your question. You have simply asserted they are there without any evidence.

The problem with your question is that you are claiming that the idea of a limiting value 'can lead to logical and philosophical inconsistencies', without a shred of justification. Moreover, the 'analogy' you offer concerning the HUP is a red herring. You might just as well cite Special Relativity as an example of the dangers of extrapolation from common sense.
If we take the series 0.999..., it can be shown mathematically that the limit = 1. You and I might have intuitive doubts about that. We might say that surely, although it approaches 1 it can't be the same as 1. And that is the difference between us and proper mathematicians- we don't, ultimately, understand the subject properly. Some mathematical ideas, such as infinity, are very counter intuitive, but mathematicians have established their properties rigorously, so raising common-sense objections to them is rather misguided.

Proof by authority? Not downvoting because I agree with the fact that the claim is unexplained and unsupported. But the second para is brazenly: Mathematicians say it, so its right You can then replace mathematician by phycisist, scientist... leaders and you get something egregious

@Rushi I am afraid that you are talking complete nonsense owing to the fact that you are overlooking the nature of mathematical truth, namely that it is the result of applying the rules of mathematics to axioms. You might just as well object that the PGA should not be consulted on the rules of golf, as that would be a fallacious proof by authority.

You dont seem to have a clue of the history of mathematics. There were no axioms in mathematics at large (geometry was an exception) for 2000 years before the late 19th century push to axiomatize ALL of math. Aside from geometry take 1. Algebra
2. Calculus
3. Probability and Statistics
4. Number Theory
5. Graph theory
6. Linear Algebra
7. Group Theory
8. Differential Equations
9. Mathematical Logic
10. Real Analysis.
Now check when these subjects were first formulated and when their satisfactory axiomatizations

@rushi, many thanks, but no time for that today. My point is yes, appeal to authority can be a mistake, but not as big a mistake as a non-mathematician claiming well-established mathematical results are wrong simply because they seem counter intuitive. All the best!

Thank you for your reponse. Not understanding how it works doesn't mean it's correct. And using the appeal to authority Fallacy just made what you said nonsensical.
When someone says limit of f when x goes to infinity is k is definitely a wrong wording, who told us that f(x) will stay an f and not become something else(another vector space) when we take  x to infinity?

@HAMDI ABDERRAHMENE Following your replies to the different comments and answers, may I propose to look up the introduction to continuous functions in the early chapter of a textbook on calculus? - Concerning your last comment: Of course, a function is not necessarily continuous in each point x_0 of its domain of definition. One obstruction might be that the limit does not exist, an other obstruction that the limit exists but is different from f(x_0).

@JoWehler , thank you for the proposal and for the help, sir. I have read multiple books on the subject and I completely understand what you are saying. However, I've come to realize that the wording used in discussing limits doesn't accurately reflect what a limit is.
Saying that the limit is 'equal to' is nonsensical. Instead, we should say "it approaches," and we should replace the '=' sign with '→'. In my worldview—which I often criticize in order to develop a better ontological brain model—these expressions definitely don't mean the same thing in any dimension.

@HAMDIABDERRAHMENE The limit is not approaching. The limit is the value which the sequence of function values approaches.

@JoWehler Thank you, sir. Seeing the incorrect wording people use on the internet confused me, but after reading your (and others') responses and doing some research, it became clear that misinterpreting the limit is erroneous, but there's nothing inherently wrong with the limit itself.

@HAMDIABDERRAHMENE You are wellcome :-)
